# error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number

Tags: curl

Whenever I am executing the below, why I am getting the below error ?

I have downloaded curl from here: https://curl.haxx.se/dlwiz/

C:>curl -X POST -vu webui:webuisecret https://localhost:8080/oauth/token -k -H "Accept: application/json" -d "password=secret&username=ales&grant_type=password&scope=read%20write&client_secret=webuisecret&client_id=webui"

```
C:\>curl -X POST -vu webui:webuisecret https://localhost:8080/oauth/token -k -H "Accept: application/json" -d "password=secret&username=ales&grant_type=password&scope=read%20write&client_secret=webuisecret&client_id=webui"
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number
* stopped the pause stream!
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number

C:\>
```